# Python Pyglet Problem (cords of the sprite)

Tags: python, sprite, pyglet

(I am not english. Hope you understand.)

Hi, I'm trying to move my "start_button" sprite to x = 150, but it'll duplicate it.
Here's the code:

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window()
window.clear()


#ON_TEXT
def ontext(txt):
    start_button.x = 150


#INTERVAL
def interval(int):
    print("Running")
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(interval, 1/30)


#SPRITES
def paint():
    start_button.draw()
start_button_pic = pyglet.image.load("start_button.png")
start_button = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(start_button_pic)


#PUSH_HANDLERS
window.push_handlers(
    on_text=ontext,
    on_draw=paint,
)


pyglet.app.run()
print("Done")
```

Thanks for answers!

Andrew

Comment: Please add more context and elaborate the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the window, before drawing the sprite:

```py
def paint():
    window.clear()
    start_button.draw()
```

The `clear` method clears the color and depth buffer (see [`pyglet.window`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/window.html)). Actually, the sprite is not duplicated, but the sprite drawn in the previous frames is still there because the color buffer was never cleared.